# cancelling a function

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, task

i have a function that makes a few http requests, and runs in a task.
that function can be interrupted in the middle, since i cant abort the task i added some boolean conditions in the function. 
example:

```
public int foo(ref bool cancel)
{
    if(cancel)
    {
        return null
    }
    //do some work...
    if(cancel)
    {
        return null
    }
    //http webrequest
    if(cancel)
    {
        return null
    }
 }
```

thisworked pretty good, although this is quite some ugly code.

another problem is when i already executed the web request, and it takes time for me to get the response than the function cncelation takes a lot of time (till i get a response).

is there a better way for me to check this? or mybe i should use threads instead of task?

**edit**

i added a cancelation token: declared a cancelationTokenSource, and passed its token to the task

```
CancellationTokenSource cncelToken = new CancellationTokenSource();
Task t = new Task(() => {foo()},cancelToken.token);
```

when i do cancelToken.Cancel();
i still wait for the response,  and the tsk isnt cancelling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tasks support cancellation - see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997396.aspx).

Here's a quick snippet.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var token = new CancellationTokenSource();
        var t = Task.Factory.StartNew(
            o =>
            {
                while (true)
                    Console.WriteLine("{0}: Processing", DateTime.Now);
            }, token);

        token.CancelAfter(1000);
        t.Wait(token.Token);
    }
}
```

Remember to wait for the task using the provided cancellation token. You ought to receive an OperationCanceledException.

Comment: but its simular to my solution. only thins is that my task calls a function, and that function does not know the cancelation token. i will still have to check if the cancelation is requested. i can use a cncelation token, but than i will still have to waite for the response to come back. i want to cancel it before that.

Comment: Not really - the need to poll on the cancellation token is only if you have some cleanup to perform. If there isn't any cleanup the task will silently stop executing your code.

Comment: i edited the question, tried using cancelation token. @ananthonline

Comment: thanks that worked great! now i got a different problem, i cant reuse the task. when i try to use new Task(), than the task is still in a canceled state. when i use task.factory.startnew() it works in creating the new task, but still the task has the same status. @ananthonline

Comment: ok, with a little playing around, i found the answer. all i needed to do was dispose the task but it threw exceptions becuse it didnt cancel yet, so i just looped a bit waiting for the cancelation to accure, and than disposed the task. **tanks @ananthonline you helped me a lot!!**

Comment: Glad I could help. Please mark this as the answer so others who come by find it too.